# Links redirecting to "#"

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a menu on a website, and it keeps redirecting to the page I'm creating no matter what I put in the href tags. I can't figure out what's causing it, I figured maybe another set of eyes could help me figure it out.

https://gist.github.com/b3f3abc42c517c8ba7ab

EDIT: fixed link

Comment: please post some code here so we can see

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: This link is broken.

Comment: I'm not getting the `gist` of what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is

```
<a href="http://adammcgee.com/clients/sdaysrodeo/file.html">file</a>
```

and not

```
<a href src="http://adammcgee.com/clients/sdaysrodeo/file.html">file</a>
```

the attribute src is used with

```
<img>
```

for example

```
<img src="image.gif">
```

Answer (score 0):

the address you give us for you gist is bad.
it is not

```
https://gist.github.com/b3f3abc42c517c8ba7ab.git
```

but

```
https://gist.github.com/b3f3abc42c517c8ba7ab
```

without "git" at the end

then the only link I found in your menu is not correct.

it is

```
<a href src="http://adammcgee.com/clients/sdaysrodeo/sdays-rodeo/announcer/#">PRCA</a>
```

it should nor finish by a "#" and you should have the extension of the page, like :

```
http://adammcgee.com/clients/sdaysrodeo/sdays-rodeo/announcer/page.html
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Audrey. I've still got two problems: 
One, I'm not linking to my own pages, so I have no idea what extension those files have. 
Two, no matter what I put in there, it is still linking to itself. I just replaced it with "http://google.com" and it still links back to itself.

Comment: 'm not linking to my own pages, so I have no idea what extension those files have. => Could you show the site where you want to make a link.  Maybe i can help you to find the links.

Comment: I got it. That was the issue, I was used to using "src" because of the images, and so as soon as I took those out, it's working perfectly. Thank you again for your help!